# Angular JS disable touch scroll except on certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm building a web application for deployment on an iPad and we're looking for an approach that will disable scrolling on the entire view, except for certain divs. Ideally it would be great to be able to apply a `scroll` class or something to the div and only permit the `scroll` classes to scroll.

What should the Angular approach be here? I've seen a variety of JQuery and pure Javascript approaches across the web but all of them seem pretty messy and not necessarily bullet proof.

Comment: Are you looking to set the height of the window so no scroll bar shows up on the window of your app? Can you set a height to your main container?

Comment: Hm I suppose that could be one approach. The way I was thinking was catching the `touchMove` javascript events and doing something there.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to determine the height of the device window (allowing you to use any deivce/pc) and setting the max-height of your div in ng-style.

```
$scope.windowHeight = $window.innerHeight; //might need to subtract 30 pixels for side scrollbar if needed.
$scope.innerDivHeight = Math.ceil($scope.windowHeight / 3) //Whatever scale you want your inner divs to be.
```

then

```
<div class="container" ng-style="{'max-height': windowHeight+'px', 'overflow':'none'}">
    <div class="innerDiv" ng-style="{'max-height': innerDivHeight+'px', 'overflow':'auto'}">
    </div>
</div>
```

You will probably have to fudge with it a bit, but this way it will work for both desktops and iPads the same, without introducing platform specific requirements. Notice the overflow none for do not scroll, and auto for yes, do scroll within this div if it exceeds the height.

Like I said, this may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you do not need any extra complexity to do this.